# Execute fail in perl dbi

Tags: perl, daemon, dbi

Piece of code. Script must become a demon, connect to two databases, and constantly check some fields. But i receive error. Log `DBD::Pg::st execute failed: SSL connection has been closed unexpectedly at ./remote_imap.pl line 55.`

Log of database is empty.

```
my $daemon = Proc::Daemon->new;
Proc::Daemon::Init({
      work_dir     => '/home/olex/develop',
      child_STDOUT => '/home/olex/develop/output.file',
      child_STDERR => '+>>debug.txt',
      pid_file     => 'remote_imap.pid'
      });
if (Proc::PID::File->running({dir=>'/home/olex/develop', verify=>1})) {
print "Already running\n";
exit 0;
}
my @kids = (0..3);
my @childs;
my $kid_pid;
my ($dbname,$dbuser,$dbpass) = ('***','**','***');
my ($dbhost, $dbhost_ag, $dbport) = ('192.168.0.**', '192.168.0.**', '5432');
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Pg:dbname=$dbname;host=$dbhost;port=$dbport", $dbuser, $dbpass,
                      { RaiseError => 1
                      , AutoCommit => 0 })
    or die $DBI::errstr;
my $dbh_ag = DBI->connect("dbi:Pg:dbname=$dbname;host=$dbhost_ag;port=$dbport", $dbuser, $dbpass,
                        { RaiseError => 1
                        , AutoCommit => 0 })
            or die $DBI::errstr;
my $status;
my $continue = 1;
$SIG{TERM} = sub { $continue = 0 };
while ($continue) {
foreach $kid_pid (@kids) {
$status = $daemon->Status($kid_pid);
if (!$status){
      $kid_pid = $daemon->Init( { 
                    work_dir     => '/home/olex/develop',
                    pid_file     => 'kid_pid.pid',
                    exec_command => 'perl /home/olex/develop/remote_imapd.pl',
                 } );
                 }
         push @childs, $kid_pid;
                 }

  my @params;
  $params[0] = 2; #DB_USERS_REMOTE_STATUS_PROCESSING
  $params[1] = 1; #DB_IN_QUEUE_STATUS_NEW
  my $childs_proc = join(',', @childs);
# Fetch new records
  my $q = "select id from queues.queue_in where status=? and user_remote_id>? order by date_create asc";
  my $sth_ag = $dbh_ag->prepare($q);
  my $rv_ag = $sth_ag->execute($params[1], 0);
  my $id = $sth_ag->fetchrow_array();
  print $id, "\n";
  *
  *
  *
  sleep(0.0001);

}
$dbh->disconnect();
$dbh_ag->disconnect();
```

If i delete this code, works correctly.

```
foreach $kid_pid (@kids) {
$status = $daemon->Status($kid_pid);
if (!$status){
      $kid_pid = $daemon->Init( { 
                    work_dir     => '/home/olex/develop',
                    pid_file     => 'kid_pid.pid',
                    exec_command => 'perl /home/olex/develop/remote_imapd.pl',
                 } );
                 }
         push @childs, $kid_pid;
                 }
```

perl v5.18.2
postgresql v8.4

What could be the problem?

Comment: You may be happy with your own unique coding standards, but if you ever want anyone else to help you with your code then it would be better to write something more usual. This is pretty much unreadable for me.

Comment: If you remove the section of code you say, then you are left with an unclosed `foreach` statement, and so the code won't compile. Did you mean that you remove the entire `foreach`?

Comment: Yes, all entire `foreach`.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first scripts on PERL

Comment: There is nothing special about Perl that requires different formatting. If you wrote code like that in *any* language it would be incomprehensible.

Comment: This is my first scripts at all. (not counting the small on bash)

Comment: Then you should write just one or two lines at a time and *test* your code to make sure it compiles and runs. Writing that much code in one shot makes it *much* more likely that you have a bug, and you have to search *many more* lines to find it.

Comment: I wrote without what part of the code, script works correctly. Queries to another database (which I do not fit here, work correctly).

Comment: It looks like you're trying to do something in parallel here but you're doing it the wrong way. Use something like Parallel::ForkManager and make sure you set up your connections AFTER forking. Also please indent your code in a sane way if you're going to ask for troubleshooting help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the DB after you fork your kid daemon. It has been my experience DB connections almost never survive a fork.

That's why it works when you remove the fork.

Comment: I wish my phone had a context sensitive autocorrect with a "talking tech" mode.